# Can't save files on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, files, downloads

Recently i have installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my MacBook. Everything it's ok except for the fact that every time i want to download a file from Firefox (a wallpaper for example) or save a program (created in Kate text editor), either Firefox or Kate are not responding. Any ideas what it could be?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is it just Firefox and Kate editor or have you tried seeing if you can't save files at all?

Open Firefox, go to Preferences > General > Downloads, click "Browse" and see where the files are being saved.